# static_assert always triggering in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, constexpr, static-assert

I wrote the following code to find the first index in a tuple containing a given type.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t H, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index_impl(Tuple tup, std::index_sequence<H, I...> seq, std::size_t ret = 0) {
        if (std::is_same<T, typename std::tuple_element<H, Tuple>::type>::value)
            ret = H;
        else ret = tuple_type_index_impl<T>(tup, std::index_sequence<I...>{});
        return ret;
    }

    template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t H>
    constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index_impl(Tuple tup, std::index_sequence<H> seq) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, typename std::tuple_element<H, Tuple>::type>::value, "type not in tuple!");
        return H;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index(Tuple tup) {
    return detail::tuple_type_index_impl<T>(tup, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>{});
}

class a {};
class b {};
class c {};
class d {};

std::tuple<a, b, c> abc;

int main() {

    printf("b is index : %zu\n", tuple_type_index<d>(abc));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem that I have is if you try to find the index for any type but `c` the `static_assert` will trigger. I'm not even sure why it's going all the way to the ending function when you try to find the index of types `a` or `b`.

If you remove the `static_assert` the return values are correct, but it will return a value for types that are not in the tuple.

---

**Inspired by the marked answer, I have reworked my implementation.**

[It is available on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3f137bf3cdb4c73)

This version should work on clang++ and g++ instead of just on MSVC.

Comment: Wich compiler (and wich command line / flags) are you using? With g++ (4.9.2) and clang++ (3.5) I get a lot of errors.

Comment: perhaps you should replace that `if` by a compile-time branch, like `std::enable_if`

Comment: you do know about [std::get (tuple)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), right? It cat get an index based on type.

Comment: @max66 msvc with std:c++latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is that you don't write a right terminal (index sequence empty) `tuple_type_index_impl()` function.

En passant, `0` value (in case of "type not found") isn't a good idea (IMHO) because you could confuse with "first type".

I've modified your example in the following

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename T, typename Tuple>
      constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index_impl
         (const Tuple &,
          const std::index_sequence<> &,
          std::size_t ret = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value)
       { return ret; }

   template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t H, std::size_t ... I>
      constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index_impl
         (const Tuple & tup,
          const std::index_sequence<H, I...> & seq,
          std::size_t ret = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value)
       {
         return std::is_same<T, typename std::tuple_element<H, Tuple>::type>::value
            ? H
            : tuple_type_index_impl<T>(tup, std::index_sequence<I...>{}, ret);
       }
 }

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index (const Tuple & tup)
 {
   return detail::tuple_type_index_impl<T>
      (tup, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>{});
 }

class a {};
class b {};
class c {};
class d {};

int main()
 {
   std::tuple<a, b, c> abc;

   std::cout << "a is index: " << tuple_type_index<a>(abc) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "b is index: " << tuple_type_index<b>(abc) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "c is index: " << tuple_type_index<c>(abc) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "d is index: " << tuple_type_index<d>(abc) << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Give me some time and I try to prepare a simpler example.

**--- EDIT: added example ---**

You're working with types, so there isn't need of create and pass to function tuple (and index sequences) objects.

I've prepared an example based on a (SFINAE based) `tupleTypeIndexHelper` struct; is working with types only so you use as

```
tuple_type_index<a, std::tuple<a, b, c>>()
```

or (when `abc` is an istantiation of `std::tuple<a, b, c>`) as

```
tuple_type_index<b, decltype(abc)>()
```

The following example works (at least: with g++ 4.9.2 and with clang++ 3.5) with C++11 too

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t Ind>
      struct tupleTypeIndexHelper
       {
         static constexpr std::size_t  dimT { std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value };

         template <std::size_t I = Ind>
            static typename std::enable_if<(I >= dimT), std::size_t>::type func ()
          { return dimT; }

         template <std::size_t I = Ind>
            static typename std::enable_if<(I < dimT), std::size_t>::type func ()
          {
            using typeI = typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type;

            return std::is_same<T, typeI>::value
               ? I
               : tupleTypeIndexHelper<T, Tuple, I+1U>::func();
          }
       };

 }

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index ()
 { return detail::tupleTypeIndexHelper<T, Tuple, 0U>::func(); }

class a {};
class b {};
class c {};
class d {};

int main()
 {
   using  t3 = std::tuple<a, b, c>;

   std::cout << "a is index:   " << tuple_type_index<a, t3>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "b is index:   " << tuple_type_index<b, t3>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "c is index:   " << tuple_type_index<c, t3>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "d is index:   " << tuple_type_index<d, t3>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "int is index: " << tuple_type_index<int, t3>() << std::endl;

   std::tuple<a, b, c> abc;

   std::cout << "a is index: " << tuple_type_index<a, decltype(abc)>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "b is index: " << tuple_type_index<b, decltype(abc)>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "c is index: " << tuple_type_index<c, decltype(abc)>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "d is index: " << tuple_type_index<d, decltype(abc)>() << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your second example. I reworked mine and used `enable_if` for branching, but I still was not able to get `static_assert` to trigger properly across compilers. On MSVC it never ran and on g++ and clang++ it always ran. So I agree that SFINAE is the way to go. I also added your idea of putting the tuple type in the template args.